# NestJS Swagger oAuth2 (oAuth0) to bearer token in header

Tags: oauth-2.0, nestjs, swagger-ui, auth0, nestjs-swagger

this is my code:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerCustomOptions, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import * as config from 'config';
import * as  crypto from 'crypto';

async function bootstrap() {
    const serverConfig = config.get('conf');
    console.log(`Environment:` + serverConfig.env);
    console.log(`Running Port:` + serverConfig.server.port);
    const teanat = 'MY_AUTH0_DOMAIN'
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
    const docBuilderConfig = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('Awesome Middleware')
        .setDescription('Represents the middleware api services')
        .setVersion('1.0')
        .addOAuth2(
            {
                type: 'oauth2',
                flows: {
                    implicit: {
                        tokenUrl: `${teanat}/oauth/token`,
                        authorizationUrl: `${teanat}/authorize?audience=${`${teanat}/api/v2/`}&nonce=${nonce}`,
                        scopes: {} // { openid: openid, ... }
                    },
                },
            },
        )
        .build()
    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, docBuilderConfig);
    const swaggerCustomOptions: SwaggerCustomOptions = {
        'customSiteTitle': 'Middle Api',
        'explorer': true,
        'swaggerOptions': {
            persistAuthorization: true,
            oauth2RedirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
            oauth: {
                clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
            }
        }
    }
    SwaggerModule.setup('/', app, document, swaggerCustomOptions);
    app.enableCors();
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header("X-powered-by", "My Company");
        res.header("Server", "My Server");
        next();
    });
    await app.listen(4200);
}
bootstrap();
```

I go to the login page just like in the client web app
and then the token return on the URL prams which I redirect to
(localhost:4200?token_access=MY_YOKEN)
I want this token to be injected to the header where the control use this auth2 with the same auth name